# Delete an array of pointers

Tags: c++

I'm struggling with removing the array from the memory.. it was allocated dynamically. I'd love some help, thanks!

```
 void RemoveAllocationOfIntegerArray(int** arr, int size) {
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            delete arr[i];
            arr[i] = NULL;
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: How was it allocated? Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: Simple stop using "C" style arrays and start using std::vector<> or in this case std::vector<std::vector<int>>, . If needed you could manage the life cycle with a std::unique_ptr to such a vector. But usually it is not needed. If possible avoid manually managing new/delete calls. (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/)

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: there can be almost no reason to dynamically allocate an int

Comment: Please be more specific than "I'm struggling". What is the nature of your struggle?

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need these lines:

```
arr[i] = NULL;
// or
arr = NULL;
```

Next, you should delete arrays using `delete[]` operator. So, replace

```
delete arr[i];
```

with:

```
delete[] arr[i];
```

Another point is, you can free memory using `delete` or `delete[]` only if it is allocated with `new` or `new[]`.

Lastly, You don't need to go backward when freeing. It is not necessary (except for some odd cases).

Comment: presumably arr[n] is a dynamically allocated int?

Answer (score 0):

Example of using std::vector, or std::vectorstd::vector<int>

```
#include <format>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void function_on_2d_data(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& values) // pass non const so you can modify values.
{
    values[1][1] = 7;
}

void show_2d_data(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& values) // pass const, show should not modify content
{
    for (const auto& row : values)
    {
        for (const auto& value : row)
        {
            std::cout << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

// a function returning dynamically allocated 2d arrays (much more safe then int** with no size info);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> create_2d_data()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> values(4, std::vector<int>(3, 1)); // This does all the "new"-ing for you, and set values in each row to 1
    return values;
}

int main()
{
    // create a 2d datastructure containing 4 row and 3 columns;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> values = create_2d_data();
    std::cout << std::format("values has {0} rows\n", values.size()); // see size information is returned too

    function_on_2d_data(values);
    show_2d_data(values);

    return 0;

    // values goes out of scope and it will do all the "delete"-ing for you
}
```